# Get cursor position after clicking a textbox in Katalon

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, build-automation, katalon-studio

I'm new to automation testing.

I'm doing GUI automation testing. I have to test whether the cursor position in a specific textbox remains or not after using Alt+Tab, then going back to the website.

I'm thinking about getting the cursor position before and after using Alt+Tab, them comparing two variables. However, I can't find any documentation about this.

Where should I get this documentation? Or if there are other ways to solve the problem, please tell me

Sorry for my bad English. I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Since Katalon is based on Selenium, you can switch to Selenium commands. Here is an example for Chrome, using `DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(driver)` to switch between Katalon's WebUI Keywords and Selenium.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "DriverFactory.getChromeDriverPath()")
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()
DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(driver)
```

Than you can do something like

```
println(driver.switchTo().activeElement().getLocation())
//do what you need to use Alt+Tab
println(driver.switchTo().activeElement().getLocation())
```

And you will get two different locations printed, something like:

```
(621, 260)
(149, 260)
```

NOTE:

You will need to import the following (or press `CTRL+SHIFT+O` for automatic imports):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory
```